# error cs2001 source file could not be found 2018

Tags: unity-game-engine

Ever since i open my project in unity today every script existed/Created have been given me

**Error cs2001 source file "ScriptName.Cs" could not be found**

I have reinstalled Unity, Tried Updating it and even created a new project. Still same outcome.

Ever time i tried attached my scripts to a object, it's have given me the error

**Can't add script behaviour VisualContainerAsset",Can't Add Script "The script needs to derive from MonoBehaviour!"**

Here is some pics how it's looks after i create a C# Script.

[image: First Pic]

[image: Second Pic]

[image: Third Pic]

Sorry if i sound a bit confused!

UPDATE!:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Malware Bytes was the problem, it would't allow mono developed.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show me one of the scripts? Maybe it misses some of the imports (using UnityEngine;) at the top. Or maybe they don't inherit from MonoBehaviour (classname: MonoBehaviour). It's strange nonetheless...

Comment: I Updated the post with the script in it. It weird.... even scripts that have been working in the past isn't working anymore.

Comment: You got no clue of somebody that can help me out??